# The square of n+1-th prime is less than the product of the first n primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

I wanted to prove the following question in an elementary way not using Bertrand postulate or analytic estimates like $x/\log x$. The question is 
$$
p_{n+1}^2<p_1p_2\cdots p_n,\qquad(n\geq4)
$$

I made the following argument. Does anyone have some opinion or simpler ideas to complete.

We consider two cases:
Case 1: $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_n-1$ is composite: then there will be a prime factor  $q\leq\sqrt{N}$, and of course $q$ is not any of the $p_i$'s. therefore $p_{n+1}\leq q\leq\sqrt{N}$. So $p_{n+1}^2<N+1$.

Case 2: $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_n-1$ is prime. Then???

Answer (score 6):

The inequality 
$$p_{n+1}^2<p_1p_2\cdots p_n$$
for $n>3$  is called [Bonse inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality), and Bonse gave a completely elementary proof in
 Bonse, H. (1907). "Über eine bekannte Eigenschaft der Zahl 30 und ihre Verallgemeinerung". Archiv der Mathematik und Physik 3 (12): 292–295. It is also proved in the book of Uspensky and Heaslet, Elementary Number Theory,
on pages 87-89. 
An online solution can be found at [art of problem solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1065643s1_bonse_inequality). A further online proof is in [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=G6nz_gNbktcC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=proof+of+Bonse+inequality+for+primes&source=bl&ots=IpGYVx9AaY&sig=O0MC0sYWP_0b35gMcU3BeutEZWQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBTgUahUKEwjKu8fH4enGAhUmZ3IKHXkkAL8#v=onepage&q=proof%20of%20Bonse%20inequality%20for%20primes&f=false), Theorem 13.
Basically the proof uses 
$$
n-m+1<p_m
$$
for $m=[n/2]$, and $p_{n+1}<p_1\cdots p_m$. Then
\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}^2 & < (p_1\cdots p_m)(p_1\cdots p_m) \\
 & < (p_1\cdots p_m)(p_{m+1}p_{m+2}-p_{2m})\\
 & < p_1\cdots p_n.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to do an induction on the primes numbers, where
$$p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5...$$
And use the theorem saying that 
$$p_{n+1}\leq 2p_n.$$

Comment: This is Bertrand's postulate, which the OP specifically is trying to avoid using.

Answer (score 0):

Proof using induction:

Base: let $n\geq 4\colon 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 210 > 121 = 11^2$.

Assume it holds for $k\in\mathbb{Z}\colon p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_k > p_{k+1}^2$. We want to prove $p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_k\cdot p_{k+1} > p_{k+2}^2$. By Bertrand's postulate $\exists q\in\mathbb{P}\colon p_{k+2}<q<2p_{k+1}$.

It's enough to show $p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_{k+1}>4p_{k+1}^2$ beacuse $4p_{k+1}^2>q^2\geq p_{k+2}^2$. The last inequality holds beacause any if the next prime numbers greater than $p_{k+1}$ can't be smaller than the next prime $p_{k+2}$. Clearly $p_{k+1}>4$ so
\begin{align*}
4p_{k+1}^2<p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_{k+1}<4p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_{k}\Leftrightarrow p_{k+1}^2<p_1\cdot p_2\dots \cdot p_{k}
\end{align*}
The last inequality holds based in the inductive assumption.

The proof is form: https://www2.cms.math.ca/crux/v42/n4/Malikic_42_4.pdf

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE! I think the OP specifically does not want to use Bertrand's Postulate.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for pointing out, I missed this part. Should I delete the solution or leave it just in case somebody finds it useful?

Answer (score -4):

Consider $a = p_1 p_2 p_3 \dots p_n p_{n+1}$

All the prime divisors of $a$ must be less than $< a^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Therefore $p_{n+1} < a^{\frac{1}{2}} = (p_1 p_2 p_3 \dots p_{n} p_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Conclusion : $(p_{n+1})^2 < p_1 p_2 p_3 \dots p_n p_{n+1}$

Comment: it is just playing with formula not a proof!

Comment: The prime divisors of $6$ are not all less than $\sqrt 6$.